# How to create a Camel route which takes XML and bind some data to JPA annotated POJO?

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jaxb, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel and mock testing so here it goes...

I have an XML with no XSD schema which I have no influence on. Child elements of this XML hold data which I want to bind to my business pojo. This POJO (WeatherCurrent) is already JPA annotated and I was thinking of adding JAXB annotation so the splitted XML could be mapped to my POJO.

As this XML has a root element and I only want its childs (metData) I have a problem how to annotate my POJO as I can not use @XmlRootElement.

This is partialy described here: http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html at *Streaming big XML payloads using Tokenizer language* chapter. My POJO is like *order* xml element in that example. I need just a few elements out of metData xml element to map to my POJO fields.

There is also a chapter *Partial marshalling/unmarshalling* at http://camel.apache.org/jaxb.html but there is no JAVA DSL example (a must), nor how to annotate the pojo to work with XML fragments.

So far I have this test code:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.camel.EndpointInject;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class WeatherCurrentTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @EndpointInject(uri = "file:src/test/resources")
    private ProducerTemplate inbox;

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                DataFormat jaxbDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat("com.mycompany.model.entities.weather");// WARNING two packages for JaxbDataFormat

                from("file:src/test/resources/?fileName=observation_si_latest.xml&noop=true&idempotent=false")
                .split()
                .tokenizeXML("metData")
                .unmarshal(jaxbDataFormat)
                .to("mock:meteo");          
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testMetData() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:meteo");
        mock.expectedMessageCount(9);

        File meteo = new File("src/test/resources/observation_si_latest.xml");
        String content = context.getTypeConverter().convertTo(String.class, meteo);
        inbox.sendBodyAndHeader(content, Exchange.FILE_NAME, "src/test/resources/observation_si_latest.xml");

        mock.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

}
```

The XML (observation_si_latest.xml) comes in this form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data id="MeteoSI_WebMet_observation_xml">
    <language>sl</language>
    <metData>
        <domain_altitude>55</domain_altitude>
        <domain_title>NOVA GORICA</domain_title>
        <domain_shortTitle>BILJE</domain_shortTitle>
        <tsValid_issued>09.03.2012 15:00 CET</tsValid_issued>
        <t_degreesC>15</t_degreesC>
    </metData>
    <metData>
        <domain_meteosiId>KREDA-ICA_</domain_meteosiId>
```

I left out lots of elements of the metData elements for brevity. I want to map (amongs others) domain_title to my JPA annotated POJO's station field and later save it database, hopefully all in one smart and short Camel route.

The POJO (no JAXB annotations yet):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="weather_current")
public class WeatherCurrent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String station;

    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="successfully_updated")
    private Date successfullyUpdated;

    private short temperature;

    @Column(name="wind_direction")
    private String windDirection;

}
```

I also left out lots of fields and methods.

So the idea is to map the value of the *domain_title* to WeatherCurrent POJO's *station* field and to do so for each metData element and save a list of WeatherCurrent objects to database.

Any advice on the best way on how to implement this is welcome.

Comment: First off split takes a parameter. Secondly how about an xpath or an xlst to remove data from the XML?  You can Marshal the XML, or access the data with xpath or xlst.  What works best?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I had one wrong assumption of not being able to use the @XmlRootElement. The route and the test passes with success after I annotated the POJO and added jaxb.index file beside it. Will post the solution later or tomorrow as I am on a train now.

Hours later...

The JAXB annotations on the POJO (on top of JPA ones):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="weather_current")
@XmlRootElement(name = "metData")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WeatherCurrent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @XmlElement(name = "nn_shortText")
    private String conditions;

    @XmlElement(name = "rh")
    private short humidity;

    @XmlElement(name = "msl")
    private short pressure;

    @Column(name="pressure_tendency")
    @XmlElement(name = "pa_shortText")
    private String pressureTendency;

    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @XmlElement(name = "tsValid_issued")
    private Date published;

    @XmlElement(name = "domain_longTitle")
    private String station;
```

enabled me to get a list of WeatherCurrent Exchage objects. Just for test I routed each one to my EchoBean to print out one property:

```
.unmarshal(jaxbDataFormat).bean(EchoBean.class, "printWeatherStation")
```

and EchoBean:

```
public class EchoBean {

    public String printWeatherStation(WeatherCurrent weatherCurrent) {
        return weatherCurrent.getStation();
    }
}
```

nicely prints out the names of the weather stations with the log Camel component.

The one undocumented thing that bothered me was that I had to put this jaxb.index file next WeatherCurrent java source although at http://camel.apache.org/jaxb.html it clearly says that jaxb context is initialized with

```
DataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat("com.acme.model");
```

Comment: Its a JAXB requirement, either you have a jaxb.index file, or you provide a custom ObjectFactory. See the javadoc for newInstance method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html